# 5V and 12V derived from a regulated 12V supply? Buck converter for 5V, in parallel with 12V load?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, buck

Apologies up front — this is super basic, but I’m sleep deprived and on a deadline for a personal project.

This is all DC. I have a 12 V input (via a wall-wart). I need 5 V to power some electronics (Raspberry Pi) and 12 V to power some other electronics (display). I plan to use a buck converter to drop from 12 V to 5 V.

Is there any reason I can’t just wire the 12 V load and the buck converter in parallel?

For some reason, it’s in my head that doing so is a bad idea, but I can’t come up with any reason why.

Comment: Connecting the 12 volt load and the buck converter in parallel to the 12 volt supply would be the normal thing to do.  How else would you connect them?

Comment: @PeterBennett: simple as it sounds, that's a good answer.  You should copy & paste it in below.  The only thing I'd add is if, for some reason you needed _quiet_ 12V power you may have a problem -- but if the 12V is coming from a wall-wart, there's already a switching supply in the mix, so you probably won't harm things any _more_.

Comment: I have no idea what else you would do. That was the plan all along, then while reviewing it I thought “no, that’s dangerous”. I have no idea why. Like I said, I’m on a steep sleep deficit right now, so hesitate to trust my own judgement.

Comment: Understand. Everyone's been there, where you need someone to double-check that 2+2=4 because you're seeing blurry and double on your fifth 4-hour night :-) Good luck with it, don't forget to accept the answer if it's correct, upvoting as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It works fine, as you would expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connecting the 12 volt load and the buck converter in parallel to the 12 volt supply would be the normal thing to do.